# How can I implement circular reveal/ripple effect when user clicks on a CardView? [Appcelerator]

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I want to set a circular reveal/ripple effect on a CardView when a user clicks on it, like when you click on a button:

[image]

All I could find was how to implement this effect on native Android, but not on Titanium, and also I couldn't find too much information about Animations on Titanium's documentation.

Comment: the ripple effect works by default on buttons/listitems and probably some more. (don't use it really), but it is implemented in some places already ;)

Comment: Instead of ripple effect, I suggest to use a background color change on tap/click. Ripple effect is hardly seen on buttons or menu-items in real usage. It is only visible properly if you keep touching button. Mathematically, clicking or tapping takes 200-300ms & ripple effect in this duration is just useless. Still if you want this effect, you should try **Ti SDK 6.2.0.GA** as I guess it can be done using latest SDK version, below this sdk Titanium has no way to do it for circular views.

Comment: I need to use this effect in order to follow the Material design guidelines.

By the way, Rene Pot, are you sure there's ripple effect by default on listitems?

Comment: yes, there was actually a PR that fixed exactly this: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/9354. If it still doesn't work you could fake it by adding a view with `touchFeedback:true` and set a `touchFeedbackColor`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this widget https://github.com/mdpauley/com.mp5systems.rippleeffect, i use it on my apps and it works on Android and iOS.

Also, the official documentation on Animation is here : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Animation

Comment: I tried that widget but it seems it won't work on my app. 

I installed it using gittio, I added the click listener to my window and I added the "rippleEffect: true" property on my CardView but nothing happens. It won't enter this conditional: if (e.source.rippleEfect) { rippleEffect.create(e); }